# Is my grandfathers table repairable?

Tags: wood-repair, butcher-block

Recently came across a table my grandfather made about 50 years ago. Clearly hasn’t been stored properly but I would love to save it.  I’m not sure where to start or if it’s possible. Would love thoughts on if this is something an amateur can tackle or if I should enlist a professional?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depends on how much you want to repair, or for what use. Do you have a specific purpose in mind (like, "as new", "vintage is good", "utility for the shop",...) (It'd be easy to just replace the top; the Singer cast iron frame should last for many generations on its own.)

Comment: Hi, what repairs? I see nothing that **needs** a repair, you could use now with table cloth or oilcloth, or wash and wax to use with bare top.

Comment: Vintage is good.  The tabletop feels loose like the glue holding the individual boards has given way.

Comment: I think knowing what your expected use of the table after 'repair' is and what specifically you consider the problem, will go a long way into our advice on 'fixing' it.  There is a very wide range of things that can be done with it from building a whole new table top to just putting a table cloth on it.

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  As mentioned in other comments, you may want to edit your question to provide more info. In addition to letting us know what you want to use it for and what you mean by repair, you may want to let us know what tools (hand and power) you have access to.

Answer (score 3):

We can see clearly from the second photo that the tabletop is made from multiple narrow boards and that due to water damage these have begun to separate at the top, from shrinkage and what's called *compression set*.

It's worth noting that the view of the underside shows us that not every joint has failed through the entire thickness so thanks for including that photo, it's very useful.

> thoughts on if this is something an amateur can tackle or if I should enlist a professional?

This doesn't really tell us enough since 'an amateur' covers so much ground<sup>1</sup>. As a result I was going to say in a Comment that we really can't answer this for you without much more detail, but, you can answer it for yourself relative to the following points:

- If you want to make this completely solid then the minimum 'proper' fix is to take the top off, then separate every glue joints (yes, every single one).
- Then you need to re-joint the edges so you're starting from fresh, clean wood and so that the edges are all perpendicular to the top surface.
- After jointing you'd glue this back together, which would typically require at least three long clamps and probably a handful of smaller clamps for clamping cauls. See [previous Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/229/what-is-a-good-way-to-prevent-jointed-tabletops-from-bowing-when-tightening-fast/241#241) for how clamps are commonly alternated and the use of cauls.

<sup>**Note:** I've deliberately left out the resurfacing and refinishing since those steps, although a fair amount of additional work, are relatively straightforward by comparison.</sup>

If the above sounds like something you aren't set up to do then you have your answer.

So it sounds like I'm saying get a pro to do the work for you. But I would caution that a repair to this — as in re-building, resurfacing and refinishing the top — will likely cost a lot more than simply having a new top made. Only you can decide if saving the existing top is worth it to you, and it's worth noting that a new top opens up a wealth of possibilities for you in terms of thickness, wood species and attractive figure/grain (whether solid wood or veneered plywood), as well as varied edge profiles.

However, if you are OK with replacing the top this brings the project back into the realm of something the beginner *could* do. You wouldn't need to build a new top since solid-wood countertop material<sup>2</sup> in a number of wood species, a range of widths and thicknesses is now widely available from lumber yards, home centres, some big-box stores, <strike>Ikea</strike> [Gerton discontinued in 2021] and online sources.

All you would need to do essentially is buy the material, saw it to length (if necessary<sup>3</sup>), do some light preparatory sanding and then apply your finish of choice. Many vendors offer a cutting service (often free for just one or two cuts) so you wouldn't even need to buy a saw and cut it yourself.

---

<sup>1</sup> The majority of the members here are amateurs so this spans the range from total beginner with no tools yet to experienced woodworker with a well-equipped home workshop.

<sup>2</sup> Made from many shorter, narrow strips glued together.

<sup>3</sup> There are a number of standard lengths, one of which could suit you already.